# Подскажите с рекурсией

Tags: php, рекурсия

Здравствуйте. Немного не могу разобраться  с рекурсией, а именно как его построить. 
Есть свойства (например, кол-во комнат, тип жилья и т.д) и есть его значения.
Мне нужно собрать ссылки этих значений в зависимости от  вложенности их свойств.

**Например (кол-во комнат -> тип жилья -> материал стен ):**

1. 1-komnatnie
2. 1-komnatnie/vtorichka
3. 1-komnatnie/vtorichka/kirpichnie

Возможно, я неправильно создал таблицу, поэтому не могу догнать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. n_category  - номер категории, к которой свойство принадлежит (квартиры)
2. value_properties - значение свойства
3. link  - ссылка свойства
4. name - название
5. n_prop - id- свойства (кол-во комнат, тип жилья и т.д)
6. priority  - на данный момент не несет никакой информации
7. parent  - родительский n_prop

Метод такой получился, закончить не хватило ума ((

```
   function get_data_dynamic_link($data,$parent=0){

    $tree = array();

    foreach ($data as $id=> $value) {    

        $tree[] = $value['link'];
        //$tree[] = $this->get_data_dynamic_link($data,$value['parent']);

    }

    return $tree;       
   }
```

Спасибо за любые советы.

Comment: вы в прошлый раз не могли нормально вопрос составить? или у вас там фантазия меняется постоянно. вы придумайте конечный вариант, как у вас и что должно работать, а потом задайте вопрос. а то люди время тратят, а вы новые вариации вопросов придумываете

Comment: спасибо за конструктивный ответ, очень помогли.  Данный ресурс служит для того, чтобы помогать в решении вопросов. Я вам благодарен за ответ в прошлый раз, но вопросов у меня очень много и за 5 дней идеи могут меняться .
Я не обязываю вас мне помогать и это ваше дело тратить на меня время или нет !

Comment: Нам бы побольше информации, какие данные на входе, как они устроены и какие запросы к ним будут. Вы, кажется, решили сделать таблицу, в которой расположены значения всех свойств. Тогда для выбора 1-komnatnie/vtorichka/kirpichnie и т.д. можно сделать так: как первого признака выбираем список подходящих id. Далее берем подходящие ид для второго признака, среди выбранных ид для первого признака, И т.д. Желательно чтобы первым признаком был тот, что вернет минимальное число id. Иногда такой подход работает.